# Disable HTTP completely in Heroku

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, heroku, express

We have a node.js express application running in Heroku. It handles authentication and has to be a highly secure.

We have forced redirect to HTTPS when we get HTTP request. But this does not seem to be enough. With tools like sslstrip we can POST via HTTP.

The only solution at hand seems to be disable the HTTP completely on Heroku.

How to do that? Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: How did you force a redirect?

Comment: We've used 'express-sslify' npm package. Added   'app.use(enforce.HTTPS(true));'

Comment: @siliconsenthil You should have posted that comment as an answer of your own question. It's totally valid as it's an alternative valid answer, so others not reading comments could see it as well

Answer (score 7):

According to OWASP you should not redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. See [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-*REMOVED*-_Do_Not_Perform_Redirects_from_Non-TLS_Page_to_TLS_Login_Page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_REMOVED_-_Do_Not_Perform_Redirects_from_Non-TLS_Page_to_TLS_Login_Page) for more details.

I think the better solution would be to reject the request with a message letting the user know why. You should be able to do this in a middleware function. The actual status code you return is debatable but something like this should work:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.protocol !== 'https') {
        return res.status(403).send({message: 'SSL required'});
    }
    // allow the request to continue
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether a request used https and then force a redirect using https if that is required (note the concern pointed out by @Ryan about redirecting and security). With Heroku, you can check the req headers' `x-forwarded-proto` header to make sure it is https. Here is an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var forceSSL = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  return next();
};

var app = express();
// in your app-level configurations
if (env === 'production') app.use(forceSSL);
```

Note: the Heroku load balancers are determining the `x-forwarded-proto` header before it hits your app.

Also: get an SSL certificate if you are using a custom domain with Heroku

Answer (score 1):

We've used *express-sslify* npm package. Added

```
app.use(enforce.HTTPS(true));
```